# libreadline.so.5: No such file or directory

Tags: installation, debian, libraries, packages

I just tried running a program installed through a .deb package and get this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know which library or package **libreadline** is a part of?  If so, how do I install and make sure it is version 5?

Thanks!

Comment: I see the same error when running the command using sudo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a package libreadline5 in lenny: http://packages.debian.org/lenny/libreadline5

Comment: @kirushik - Thanks! Here is another resource http://www.mathlinks.ro/viewtopic.php?t=272131